# resolve This service is not available from your country Google analytics error

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

I want to use **spatie/laravel-analytics** laravel Package to get and show stats of my site.

I follow all instructions and install that. but beacause My site hosted in a country of [restricted Countries that can not use Google analytics services](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389?hl=en), I can not access to analytics stats via API while if I use a unblocker website application all things works fine.

Because of this problem, bellow error are shown :

```
Google_Service_Exception in REST.php line 110:
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A117793508&start-date=2015-03-03&end-date=2016-03-02&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3Abrowser&sort=-ga%3Asessions: (403) This service is not available from your country
```

Is there any solution that I could resolve this Problem?

Comment: Did you try using a different hosting?

Comment: @CanCelik, I am a developer in a web hosting Co and I must be use their hosting that is located in a restricted country.

Comment: @Pitchinnate, how can I use Proxy in the remote host.

Comment: @A.B.Developer I think you would better to find a different analytics service maybe a hosted solution like http://piwik.org/ (it even has laravel laravel interface http://laravel-piwik.robbrazier.com/en/latest/)

Comment: @CanCelik, does it support all Google analytics features?

Comment: @A.B.Developer No. It's not google analytics.

Comment: @A.B.Developer you have your server send the request through a proxy. Do you actually have control over the server or are you just on shared hosting? If you are simply on shared hosting then you are probably out of luck.

Comment: yes I have control over the server but i do not kbow how to use a proxy for send requests.